# javafx, calling an element's setOnAction handler from another setOnAction?

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, javafx-8, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to make a shortcut to call the method defined in button 1's setOnAction from another element's setOnAction? This is specifically for a keyboardshortcut

An example:

```
button1.setOnAction(e->{
    doAThing();
});

keyboardShortcut.setOnAction(e->{
    button1.handle(action); //<-- any variants possible?
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this code, why don't you create a common action function and you call it from all the listeners?

```
private void listeners() {

    button1.setOnAction(e->{
        doAction();
    });

    keyboardShortcut.setOnAction(e->{
        doAction();
    });

}

void doAction() {
    System.out.println("Some Action");
}
```

Comment: I found an answer to my own problem. I call button1.fire() from the keyboard shortcut. The reason I don't do multiple doActions() is because doAction is a placeholder for many lines of code, and If I could reference the button's action code from 1 line in the shortcut, that is preferable

Comment: Actually, it doesn't make any difference. Honestly I think it's preferable the solution I proposed if you wish to log the actions and how they were triggered. If you're adding a logging line before the `doAction()`, with your method you'll receive first a "keyboard action" and then a "button action". Anyway, both solutions are valid.

Comment: Chaining events can lead to some weird bugs if you create a loop. If there's multiple people working on the project the chances that this occur are quite high, as the relation between the events is not evident and cannot be easily followed.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that you do this by calling `button1.fire();`